# How to fix git error: /example/file.js is outside repository when staging changes from within vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I try to stage changes I've made in a file by clicking the stage button in the Source control tab in vscode I get this error:

`fatal: /path/to/my/file: '/path/to/my/file' is outside repository`

it shows that the code running is :

`git add -A -- /path/to/my/file`

vscode is running the command with an absolute path, also when I run the command myself from the terminal with an absolute path it gives the same error, but when I run it with a relative path it work.

Please note that when I select `stage all changes` it works too from within vscode.

**Contents Of .git/config file :**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[branch "master"]
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/my-username/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "gitlab"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/my-username/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gitlab/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

any Idea how to make vscode run the right command when stage the changes through it ?

Comment: What is your operating system ? Have you tried the command in VS code's terminal or your OS terminal ?

Comment: Im using Mac OS Mojave , I tried the command both on the vscode terminal and the os terminal , it didn't work with the path that vscode is running the comman with, vscode is running the command with wrong path. when I run the command with correct path it works

Comment: Right. Never used git with VSC but this link shows how to add individual files using the GUI: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support have you done this ?

Comment: I think it's a cache issue of wrong filepaths by VSC.

Comment: what I've done is pressing the + button beside the file I want to stage, then I got the error.

Comment: Tough problem! Could you edit the question and add the real wrong and right file paths ?

Comment: @Niloct actually I just noticed that it is running the right path, and still give me the error , `/Users/hades-ux94/Desktop/Hádēs/Work/tonino-angularjs/src/index.ts` that's path that vscode is running the command with, and also when I run it in the terminal myself, but when I give it a relative path it works :( I'll edit the question to match the case

Comment: Perhaps it's the folder `/Hádēs`, try to rename it without accents.

Comment: @Niloct, yes It was actually because of the name of the folder, now it works perfectly, problem solved ! :))

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Comment: Now to explain why that happens, it's probably because your terminal doesn't have UTF-8 encoding I guess ?

Comment: I checked the encoding available on my terminal, I have UTF-8 and it is checked out, I don't think this is the problem

Comment: What is your `git --version` ?

Comment: its `git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)`

Comment: Could you edit the question with the content of `.git/config` file your original local repo (with accents) ?

Comment: @Niloct done...

Comment: It's exactly as my config. What happens if you clone the remote repository again, in a new directory ? git clone it to a subdir of `/Users/hades-ux94/Desktop/Hádēs/Work/` and try to add a file with full path.

Comment: same error as before

Comment: Could I checkout that here ? You can contact me see my profile.

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: Cloning your repo here, you didn't post the repo info I presume it's private, so you can contact me by e-mail with the info.

Comment: you want access to my. repo ?

Comment: I have the same setup as you, perhaps we can find the issue faster doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188444/discussion-between-hads-and-niloct).

Comment: You took so long to reply that the chat room expired. I presume you gave up on this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:
Run this git command in visual studio terminal.

```
git config core.precomposeunicode false
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. It would really help our readers if you could explain why and how your answer solves the OPs problems

Comment: After 5 differents thread, this solution finally worked for me on Mac OS Monterrey, thank's a lot !